# Process one function before another

Tags: php, global-variables, global, template-engine

I'm creating very simple e-commerce platform and i'm stuck on meta tags. I have something like this (the code is very simplified of course :P):

```
class Blabla {

    public $meta_title = 'zzzzzzz';

    function pages() {
        $this->meta_title = 'xxxxxx';
    }

    function title() {
        return $this->meta_title;
    }
}
```

Than i have index.php like this:

```
require_once('blabla.php');
$blabla= new Blabla();
<html>
    (...)
    <?php echo $blabla->title(); ?>
    (...)
    <?php echo $blabla->pages(); ?>
    (...)
</html>
```

My question is how to run pages() first and display meta() correctly?
I can add $this->pages() to __construct() but i think it's not the best way to solve my problem.

Comment: You should not use `global` inside a class. It totally destroys the class encapsulation. Instead, pass the values as parameters to the method, or create a class property that you load with a Setter.

Comment: Dont use hacks like `global` in an OOP context. Please explain what you are trying to achieve - your example code is too generic to follow

Comment: Can't you set `$meta_title` in your constructor? Also, use `private $meta_title` in your class instead of `global $meta_title`.

Comment: I have changed the code. I'm new in programming ;)
@Steve
I want to display "xxxxxx" instead of "zzzzzzz" in index.php

Comment: I know you are trying to write simplified code to make your question easier to understand, but its having the opposite result. The correct answer to this question as it currently reads would be to either call `$this->pages()` within the `title` method, or just declare `public $meta_title = 'xxxxxx';` in the 1st place. Im sure there is a reason you dont want to do that, but i have no idea what that reason might be because the code is too generic to actually illustrate your problem.

Comment: 'xxxxxx' in function pages() is assigned dynamically (i have data from API).
`$this->meta_title = $result['details']['data']['product']['name']`

Comment: OK, so why not call that api in the `title` method instead?? I can already guess its because you need more data from the api, and somehow use that in the pages method call, but again, as im only guessing, i cant help. You need to edit your question to properly explain your issue, the current dummy code is useless as it does not illustrate the complexity of the problem at all

Comment: Hmm... Yes - i think i can call API in `function title();` too. I wanted to avoid the double API call but i can think on caching results.

Comment: Well it would probably make a lot more sense to call the api in constructor, save the required data to various private member variables, and then access the required data from those variables in the other method calls. Probably you could also cache the api results on disk for x amount of time to reduce latency- but without seeing a more detailed explanation of your problem i can only offer hints not an actual solution

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I ended up with `ob_start();` + `str_replace();` + `ob_end_clean();` - i hope this is performance good ;)